# Reverse first n items of the list and return it

Tags: python

Reverse first n items of the list and return it.  If n <= 0, return the empty list. Do not consume MORE than n items of iterable.

```
  >>> reverse(4, ['f', 'o', 'o', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l'])
  ['t', 'o', 'o', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l']



  if n <= len(lst):
  return []
  else:
  for i in range(n):????What next?
```

Comment: Of the top, one mistake so far is `if n <= len(lst): return []` but the problem statement says `If n <= 0, return the empty list.` In this case, you'll always get an empty list

Comment: @Shitty.coder: You should change your nickname!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You will get more help if you [learn to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> def reverse(n, lst):
        if n <= 0:
            return []
        return lst[:n][::-1] + lst[n:]

>>> reverse(4, ['f', 'o', 'o', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l'])
['t', 'o', 'o', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l']
>>>
```

Explanation:

- `if n <= 0:`: if `n` is less than or equal to zero...
- `return []`: return an empty list. Otherwise...
- `return lst[:n][::-1]`: return **all the elements in the range `n` and reverse them**. Plus...
- `lst[n:]`: The rest of the elements past range `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_reverse(num, l):
    if num <= 0:
        return []
    return l[:num][::-1] + l[num:]

# Explanation:
# l[:num]       :    Sliced list with elements between 0 to num
# l[:num][::-1] :    Reverse of slice list
# l[num:]       :    Sliced list with elements from num to end
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_reverse(4, ['f', 'o', 'o', 't', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l'])
['t', 'o', 'o', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'l', 'l']
```